# UITextField keyboard return button should change as Done button

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield, ipod

I am having five number of textFields, say textField1,textField2,textField3,textField4,textField5.

What i want to do is that the `UITextField` keyboard return  button should change as Done button   when all the textField contains some text.
 I have tried,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([textField1.text doubleValue]!=0)
        if([textField2.text doubleValue]!=0)
            if([textField3 doubleValue]!=0)
                if([textField4 doubleValue]!=0)
                    if([textField5 doubleValue]!=0)
                    {
                        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
                    }
                    else
                        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
                    else
                        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
                    else
                        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
                    else
                        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
                    else
                        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
}
```

I also tried in

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
}
```

Both are not working... Please anyone help me...

Comment: Why are you checking the same text field again and again?

Comment: @Neo sorry, by mistake i have entered like that... now the question was edited...

Comment: @TheMechanic ya tell me dude....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you better play with textFieldShouldBeginEditing, here just check all the textfields are contains non null values,

so code should look like this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if([[tf1.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] > 0 && [[tf2.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] > 0 [[tf3.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] > 0) {
        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

//// **EDIT**

I've checked this code. It works fine. so try this and lemme know.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([self areAllFieldsNonEmpty]) {
        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
        [textField reloadInputViews];
    } else {
        [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
        [textField reloadInputViews];
    }
    return TRUE;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([self areOtherFiledsNonEmptyThan:textField]) {
        if (range.location == 0 && range.length == 0) {
            [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
            [textField reloadInputViews];
        } else if (range.location == 0 && range.length == 1) {
            [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDefault];
            [textField reloadInputViews];
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

- (NSInteger)lengthOf:(UITextField *)tf {
    return [[tf.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length];
}

- (BOOL)areOtherFiledsNonEmptyThan:(UITextField *)tf {
    BOOL isEmpty = TRUE;
    for (UITextField *textField in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && tf != textField) {
            if ([self lengthOf:textField] == 0) {
                isEmpty = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isEmpty;
}

- (BOOL)areAllFieldsNonEmpty {
    BOOL isEmpty = TRUE;
    for (UITextField *textField in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            if ([self lengthOf:textField] == 0) {
                isEmpty = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: show issue like `[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb9ba7c`

Comment: I've used only 3 textfields so just copy paste for other two. I mean you check this for all five textfields n it is goin to work for sure. no doubts about it.

Comment: and as you want to do this on keystroke event put this code under - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

Comment: no it is not working...... my requirement is,  i am entering the values to the txtfields if all the txtfield contains some text means the return key is changed into done.. after that if i delete the any one of the txtfield's text means it should show return key.....

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if([your_textField.text length]>0)

your_textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

Comment: It works on every keyboard press. It should work on when press "Search" from Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check your condition in two methods:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

So make a function for condition for reusability of code -

```
-(void)checkCondition;
```

And then do this in your `ViewController.m` class -

```
-(void)checkCondition
{
    if([txtField1.text length]>0 && [txtField2.text length]>0 && [txtField3.text length]>0 && [txtField4.text length]>0 && [txtField5.text length]>0)
    {
        txtField1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        txtField2.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        txtField3.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        txtField4.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        txtField5.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    }

    else
    {
        txtField1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        txtField2.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        txtField3.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        txtField4.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
        txtField5.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    }

}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     [self checkCondition];
     [textField reloadInputViews];
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
{
     [self checkCondition];
     [textField reloadInputViews];
}
```

Remember `space` is count as a `character`, So if you dont want to count `spaces` then first remove them from `textField.text` and then compare.